# Is it possible to avoid duplicate code when implementing methods for two similar class?

Tags: java, overloading

I have two classes: `Fish` and `Plant`. They do not inherit from any classes.

But both of them have one method called `isAlive()` which have the same implementation details. Now I have a list of fish and another list of dog and I need to remove dead fish and dead dog. I want my method to have same name but it is not possible without adding additional field to method signature. Is it possible I do not need to write additional chunk of code which does the same as the last chunk of code?

Below is the code. For class `Model`, `Fish` and `Plant` are two data members and they are ArrayList of `Fish` and `Plant` objects.

Is there any way I can write only one method called count and I do not need to add additional field to my method signature or modify my return type?

```
public class Fish{
    public boolean isAlive(){
        if(this.size > 0){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
public class Plant{
    public boolean isAlive(){
        if(this.size > 0){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public class Model{
    private int countDeadFish() {
        int totalCount = 0;
        for(Fish aFish : this.fish) {
            if(aFish.isAlive() == false) {
                totalCount += 1;
            }
        }
        return totalCount;
    }

    private int countDeadPlants() {
        int totalCount = 0;
        for(Plant plant : this.plants) {
            if(plant.isAlive() == false) {
                totalCount += 1;
            }
        }
        return totalCount;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use a `super-class` for both `Fish` and `Plant` classes because the method `isAlive()` is the same and let them extends it. And for your `Model` class you just need one of these methods which operates on the `super-class` or takes params.

Comment: https://www.tutorialsandyou.com/java/inheritance-in-java-13.html check this first

Comment: Note `if(this.size > 0) { return true; } return false;` can be replaced by `return size > 0` and `if(plant.isAlive() == false)` can be replaced by `if(!plant.isAlive())`. And `totalCount += 1;` can be replaced by `totalCount++`. This code is somewhat ... nasty.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to use inheritance, then you can use a common method:

```
public class AliveChecker {

    public static boolean isAlive(int size) {
        return size > 0;
    }

}

public class Plant{
    public boolean isAlive(){
        return AliveChecker.isAlive(this.size);
    }
}

public class Fish{
    public boolean isAlive(){
        return AliveChecker.isAlive(this.size);
    }
}
```

Comment: + for link and answer too

Answer (score 1):

Since `Fish`and `Plant` do not inherit from anything yet you can consider creating a superclass and extend from it:

```
public class LivingThing {
    protected int size = 1;
    public boolean isAlive() {
        return size > 0;
    }
}

public class Plant extends LivingThing {
}

public class Fish extends LivingThing {  
}
```

This example uses [inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) to classify `Plant`and `Fish` into the superclass `LivingThing`. You can set the `size` for example in the constructor of the `Plant` or an instance method:

```
public class Plant extends LivingThing {
    public Plant(int size){
        this.size = size;
    }
}
```

Your `Model` could then be:

```
public class Model{
    private int countDeadFish() {
        return countDead(this.fish);
    }

    private int countDeadPlants() {
        return countDead(this.plants);
    }

    private int countDead(ArrayList<LivingThing> things) {
        int totalCount = 0;
        for(LivingThing thing: things) {
            if(!thing.isAlive()) {
                totalCount++;
            }
        }
        return totalCount;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a utility method (in a utility `class` somewhere):

```
public final class Liveliness {

    private Liveliness() {
    }

    public static boolean isAlive(final IntSupplier sizer) {
        return sizer.getAsInt() > 0;
    }

}
```

Your method then becomes:

```
public boolean isAlive(){
    return Liveliness.isAlive(this::getSize);
}
```

---

Alternatively, use an `interface Life`:

```
public interface Life {

    int getSize();

    default boolean isAlive(){
        return getSize() > 0;
    }
}
```

This way, adding a `getSize` method and inheriting from `Life` will add the method.

---

Note, avoid the following antipattern:

```
if(test) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Use `return test`.

Comment: It can be called whatever you want to call it - it is "a utility `class` somewhere".

Answer (score 0):

Use interface

```
public interface LiveObject {
    boolean isAlive();
}

public class Fish implements LiveObject {
    public boolean isAlive(){
        if(this.size > 0){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public class Plant implements LiveObject {
    public boolean isAlive(){
        if(this.size > 0){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public class Model{

    private int countDead(Collection<LiveObject> objects) {
        int totalCount = 0;
        for(LiveObject obj : objects) {
            if(obj.isAlive() == false) {
                totalCount += 1;
            }
        }
        return totalCount;
    }

    private int countDeadFish() {
        return countDead(this.fish);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments it seems you can't modify `Fish` or `Plant`. Here's an approach to reduce duplication in `countDead<Something>` methods which does not require this.

Basically you want to count items in an array which satisfy certain criteria. With Java 8 you can capture this criteria in a predicate using lambdas or method references. You do not need inheritance or implementation of a certain interface for this.

```
private long countDeadFish() {
    return countDeadItems(this.fish, Fish::isAlive);
}

private long countDeadPlants() {
    return countDeadItems(this.plants, Plant::isAlive);
}

private <T> long countDeadItems(Collection<T> items, Predicate<? super T> isAlive) {
    return items.stream().filter(isAlive.negate()).count();
}
```